# matching records in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with single field like so;

```
scaffold10017|size24957-5236
scaffold10017|size24957-5236
scaffold10017|size24957-5236
scaffold10017|size24957-7124
scaffold10076|size19532-3212
scaffold10076|size19532-6287
scaffold1008|size40169-12384
scaffold1008|size40169-12399
scaffold1008|size40169-21350
scaffold1008|size40169-34740
```

I want to print a new file  that includes this field and a second field with values that increment by a value (say 100,000) every time a record does not match the previous record in field. So the output would look like this:

```
scaffold10017|size24957-5236 0
scaffold10017|size24957-5236 0
scaffold10017|size24957-5236 0
scaffold10017|size24957-7124 0
scaffold10076|size19532-3212 100000
scaffold10076|size19532-6287 100000
scaffold1008|size40169-12384 200000
scaffold1008|size40169-12399 200000
scaffold1008|size40169-21350 200000
scaffold1008|size40169-34740 200000
```

Would be grateful if anyone can suggest how to do this.

Comment: lines are separated by blank lines?

Comment: no, there should be no spaces between lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F '|' 'x!=$1{x=$1; y+=(NR==1?0:100000)}; {print $0, y}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
  BEGIN { flag = 0 } 
  NR>1 && prev != $1 { 
    prev = $1
    flag += 100000 
  } 
  { print $1"|"$2, flag }'
```

You could also set `flag = -100000` initially and eliminate the `NR>1` from condition for the second case.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F\| -v value=-100000 '
  $1 != prev {value += 100000; prev = $1}
  {print $0, value}
'
```